# What can I do with a Windows Service that with a normal application I can't do?

Tags: windows, windows-services

> Wikipedia: On Microsoft Windows
>   operating systems, a Windows service
>   is a long-running executable that
>   performs specific functions and which
>   is designed not to require user
>   intervention. Windows services can be
>   configured to start when the operating
>   system is booted and run in the
>   background as long as Windows is
>   running, or they can be started
>   manually when required.

but I can create a application that run in the background as long as Windows is running also without a Windows Service ( I can set the Run key in the registry for example ).

So my question is:

**What can I do with a Windows Service that with a normal application I can't do ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running without any interactive user logged on for example.
Calling LogonUser to impersonate other users ( normally is not allowed without changing the privileges on standard applications)
Having some benefit from service control manager, as Recovery actions in case of failure.

Comment: I can insert the application in the Startup Directory and it will be run without any interactive user. no ?

Comment: Startup dir is called when an user is logged on

Comment: @xRobot: no, putting it into the startup folder only starts it up **when** the user logs in! A Windows Service is up and running as soon as your machine (server) is up - no one needs to log in....

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous advantages

- Support for MWI Remote Starting/Stopping of services monitoring
- OS support for Failover/ notification
- SOA by default
- OS support for autostart